# How to resolve this error : spawn yarn ENOENT?

Tags: yarnpkg

Yarn Install successful:

```
C:\Users\Yael\Downloads\metamask-extension-8.0.9\metamask-extension-8.0.9>yarn
yarn install v1.22.10
[1/5] Validating package.json...
[2/5] Resolving packages...
success Already up-to-date.
Done in 2.77s.
```

Yarn dist error:
C:\Users\Yael\Downloads\metamask-extension-8.0.9\metamask-extension-8.0.9>yarn dist
yarn run v1.22.10
$ yarn build prod
$ node development/build/index.js prod
running task "prod"...
Starting 'prod'...
Starting 'clean'...
(node:12548) ExperimentalWarning: The fs.promises API is experimental
Finished 'clean'
Starting 'styles:prod'...
Finished 'styles:prod'
Starting 'scripts:deps:background'...
Starting 'scripts:deps:ui'...
Starting 'scripts:core:prod:background'...
Starting 'scripts:core:prod:ui'...
Starting 'scripts:core:prod:phishing-detect'...
Starting 'scripts:core:prod:contentscript'...
Starting 'static:prod'...
Starting 'manifest:prod'...
events.js:174
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^

```
Error: spawn yarn ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:246:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

C:\Users\Yael\Downloads\metamask-extension-8.0.9\metamask-extension-8.0.9>
```